# Locating a birth record for Mary Harris circa November 1919

Tags: birth-records, 1910s, wales

The story with Mary Harris started out with my research for [Alexander Campbell Harris](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/finding-records-of-professional-athlete-and-trainer-who-married-1911-at-cardiff) records in Wales.

Eventually I located a burial entry for Alexander at Llanelli Cemetery and they kindly provided my with a print out with the details.

I noticed on this print out that there was another person buried in the same grave. He was buried in 1935 and she (a 5 month old girl) on 30 March 1920.

I searched for a death certificate for this girl and it was as I suspected:

- Rank or Profession: Daughter of Alexander Campbell Harris
- Informant: Father Alex Harris

So my wife's Great Grandfather had a daughter that no one knew about and fits in the tree correctly:

[image: Tree]

My problem is locating her birth entry which I would make out as October / November 1919. I did an initial search and came up with a Mary Harris in the district of Kings Norton. I know this was not Llanelli but I thought it worth a short. Turns out that this Mary did not have a father on the certificate but had a mother (Gertrude Lois Harris) so this can't be our Mary.

On Mary's death certificate it said her father was a "Licensed Victualler" which I understand to be an old term for a Landlord. And I know from family that Alexanders wife Esme was a Landlord. The certificate says Brecon Arms, which has been confirmed to be in Llanelli at the time.

So that is the history. I can easily find her death but why can't I find her birth? I admit that I have assumed that the mother was Esme, but it just makes sense.

Either way, I am hitting a brick wall and it would be nice to find the correct birth entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

- 1920
- M Quarter
- Llanelly
- 11A
- 2861
- EARLEY
- HARRIS, MARY

[image: Birth]

It did not occur to me that her birth was registered in 1920!

---

I received the certificate yesterday and it was the right reference. She was born on 12 November 1919 and her mum did not register it until 1 January 1920.

She was born at home in the pub (Brecon Arms) they were landlords for. I guess with the Christmas period they would have been busy.